# One touch in dispatchTouchEvent registered multiple times

Tags: android

I'm using dispatchTouchEvent to intercept touches in my activity. This is my code for the overridden method:

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int[] l = new int[2];
    mVideoImage.getLocationOnScreen(l);
    int left = l[0];
    int top = l[1];
    int w = mVideoImage.getWidth();
    int h = mVideoImage.getHeight();
    float x = ev.getX();
    float y = ev.getY();
    if (x > left && x < (left + w) && y > top && y < (top + h)) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityVideoPlayer.class));
    }
    else {
        finish();
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

The problem is that each time I touch the screen, dispatchTouchEvent is called 2 or 3 times (usually 3), and when the code in the conditional is executed 3 times, it launches 3 ActivityVideoPlayer activities, which I don't want.

Why is this happening, and how do I get just 1 touch out of 1 touch, or at least work around this so my  ActivityVideoPlayer isn't launched 3 times? I guess I could do a single-top with that, or whatever it is that makes just 1 activity of a given kind active at a time, now that I think about it, though it would still be nice to know what's happening here.

I wonder if maybe there isn't 1 touch getting recorded for each layer on the screen where I'm touching (views + viewgroups in which they sit), in which case it seems that I should be able to consume the touch before it gets to multiple layers. I tried changing dispatchTouchEvent to return true and false to see if that would do it, but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using dispatchTouchEvent , you take all touches in your activity, if you want only detect one touch, you have to filter the touch by its type, you can do this using the MotionEvent parameter.

```
if( ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
  //launch activity video player
}
```